# when i try to inference on multiple GPUs using suprocess to start multiprocess,the time for model.generate() becomes very long

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

**This is my code to start the multi-process
**

```
for process_rank in range(args.rank*args.devices_pernode,(args.rank+1)*args.devices_pernode):
    cmd=f'''
            python inference_sample.py \
            --output_dir  {args.output_dir}/subprediction \
            --outputfile_name   {process_rank}.json \
            --model_name_or_path {args.model_name_or_path} \
            --data_path {cachedsub_dir}/{process_rank}.json \
            --temperature {args.temperature} \
            --device {process_rank%args.devices_pernode} \
            '''
    print(cmd)
    task = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                        shell=True,
                        # stdout=subprocess.PIPE
                        )
    task_list.append(task)
```

This is the code I actually use for inference.I'm using the [model.generate()](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/text_generation) method in transformers.

```
    for data_point in tqdm(lder,desc=f"{args.device}"):
        tt1=time.time()
        tp1=time.perf_counter()
        data = dict()
        input_ids=data_point["input_ids"]
        # attention_mask=data_point["attention_mask"].cuda() 
        labels=data_point["labels"]
        qualitys=data_point["qualitys"]
        #print("-----------------")
        # if int(qualitys[0])<3:
        #    #print("here======================================================")
        #    #assert 1==0
        #    continue

        new_inp=input_ids[0][labels[0]<0].unsqueeze(0)
        tt2=time.time()
        tp2=time.perf_counter()
        # if args.device=="0":
        print(f"process{args.device} before generate：{(tt2-tt1)}")
        print(f"process{args.device} before generate：{(tp2-tp1)}")
        
        if output and args.device=="0":
            print(f"input:{tokenizer.decode(input_ids[0][labels[0]<0])}")
        try: 
            full_completion=model.generate(
                inputs=new_inp, 
                temperature=args.temperature,
                top_p=0.9,
                do_sample=True,
                num_beams=1,
                max_new_tokens=600,
                eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
                pad_token_id=tokenizer.pad_token_id,
                num_return_sequences=8
                ) 
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            # continue   
            break 
        tt3=time.time()
        tp3=time.perf_counter()
        # if args.device=="0":
        print(f"process{args.device} generate：{(tt3-tt2)}")
        print(f"process{args.device} generate：{(tp3-tp2)}")
```

By measuring execution time, I found that most of the time for an iteration is focused on model.generate(). I tested 1 gpu, 2 gpus, and 8 gpus, and I found that with 8 gpus starting 8 threads, one iteration took about 25 times longer than the first two cases.
I'd like to know why and how to solve this problem.